# how to change the year in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

i have a table like this [image]

unfortunately, the date has become to the year 2021, instead, I want it into 2020, how to change that?

Comment: Fully specify the data in the spreadsheet source. Otherwise the dates will always be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is You need to change it in source excel sheet. Can you check on the date format in the excel so that it would be more easy.

Other wise build your date in the formula , this we need to be careful when we move to next year 2022

```
makedate(
2020,
DATEPART('month', #2004-04-15#),
DATEPART('day', #2004-04-15#)
)
```

You can also use tableauprep, since I dont know which version you are using I cannot recommend that.

Try this and let me know if you need more help. Thanks!